# App for Android that reads Open Street Map data but can be used as a GPS or for Directions

Tags: android, maps, gps, navigation, openstreetmap

I want to use Open Street Map data but the Open Street Map website does not have these features. The main features I need are directions and turn by turn GPS navigation.

Comment: See also [Offline map browser on Android with offline search](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82/offline-map-browser-on-android-with-offline-search) (which has a different set of requirements)

Comment: What are the features that you're missing from the OSM website? I can't see anything in your question that OSMAnd doesn't provide.

Comment: @Gilles Maybe I am mistaken. But is there a way to search a location and say tell me how to get there from here on the OSM website?

Comment: Not on http://openstreetmap.org/ itself, but OSM (the database) has all the necessary data, and there are applications both offline and online that provide navigation. For example OsmAnd on Android (which works well offline), or http://www.yournavigation.org/ if you want a webapp.

Comment: "Here" works amazingly well.  And it's free.

Answer (score 8):

[OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) can work with online or offline (pre-downloaded) OpenStreetMap data. It offers offline search and directions (pedestrian, cycling and driving). It can provide voice guidance.

The basic application is free (no cost and no ads). There is a for-pay version which allows downloading more offline maps.

Answer (score 7):

[Locus Maps](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locus-map-free-outdoor-gps/menion.android.locus) can do this and more. A very useful bonus feature here is it can import complete `.kmz` files (including images and everything) for offline use, so you can make your own travel guide (used it this way a couple of times). If you calculate your routes ahead (e.g. in the hotel, while still on WiFi), navigation should also work offline.

*Locus Maps* supports a bunch of map sources, not only OSM, but also vector maps and more. More sources are introduced via an addon ([Map Tweak](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locus-addon-map-tweak/com.mjk.locusmaptweak)).

It's good when it comes to privacy, as per default it accesses almost no private data (access to contacts must be enabled via the [contacts addon](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locus-addon-contacts/menion.android.locus.addon.contacts)), and it even has things like an [AR addon](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locus-addon-ar/menion.android.locus.addon.ar) ([check out more](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/431821/)).

Comment: What is an “AR addon”?

Comment: An addon for [Augmented Reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality). In short, AR mostly uses the camera picture of your surroundings, and enriches it with additional information. With *Locus Maps* that means you see your surroundings through the camera, and POIs get marked if any are in the "visible area" (e.g. "what's interesting over there?").