# Offline map browser on iOS with offline search

Tags: ios, gps, maps, offline

I'm looking for an offline map browsing application for an iPhone. Absolute requirements:

- Runs on iOS 7.1
- Have maps of the USA, Canada and Bahamas
- The application must be able to show the GPS position on the map (“where am I?”).
- The application must be suitable for navigating based on the downloaded maps. For example, given a street address, I must be able to search this address on the map, and show how I can travel to there.
- I must be able to easily download at least the map for a town and its suburbs. The larger the region the better.

If possible:

- Have other countries available (I'm especially interested in France and South Korea)
- Allow downloading a large area (e.g. a whole state or country), as much as my phone's storage capacity permits.
- Show both local names and transliterated names, for locales that don't use the Latin alphabet.
- Show extra data such as museums, restaurants, etc.
- Search for tourist attractions, restaurants, etc.
- Pedestrian, cycling, driving and public transport directions.
- Show transportation information (“where's does bus 42 stop?”).
- Free.

(Note: there is a [similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82/903) for Android, from which I copied many features.)

Comment: Do all your requirements are offline one's?

Comment: @Fractaliste yes

Answer (score 1):

I use [Genius Maps](http://geniusmaps.com/), which has the following features:

- non-free
- runs on iOS 7.1 (and Android 2.2 and up)
- have maps of the USA, Canada and Bahamas, as well as many other countries
- is able to show the GPS position on the map (“where am I?”).
- is suitable for navigating based on the downloaded maps.

[image]

- easily download an entire country:

[image]

- Show extra data such as museums, restaurants, etc.

[image]

---

List of all countries with maps:

- EUROPE: Albania, Andorra, Austria, Belarus, Belgium, Bosnia Herzegovina, Bulgaria, Croatia, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, FYROMacedonia, Germany, Gibraltar, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Moldova, Monaco, Montenegro, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Russia, San Marino, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, Ukraine, United Kingdom, Vatican City
- NORTH AMERICA: USA Central, USA North East, USA South East, USA West Alaska, Hawaii, Puerto Rico and Virgin Islands, Canada, Mexico
- ASIA/PACIFIC: Australia, Brunei, Indonesia, Malaysia, Maldives, New Zealand, Philippines, Singapore. Taiwan, Thailand, Vietnam
- CENTRAL/SOUTH AMERICA: Argentina, Bahamas, Brazil, Cayman Islands, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, French Guiana, Martinique, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Saint Barthelemy, Suriname, Uruguay, Venezuela
- MIDDLE EAST/AFRICA: Angola, Bahrain, Botswana, Burundi, Egypt, Israel, Ivory Coast, Jordan, Kuwait, Lebanon, Lesotho, Kenya, Malawi, Morocco, Mozambique, Namibia, Nigeria, Oman, Senegal, Saudi Arabia, South Africa, Swaziland, Tanzania, Tunisia, Uganda, United Arab Emirates, Zambia, Zimbabwe