# Free Navigation App to Find a Geolocation that works Offline without any Maps

Tags: gratis, android, offline, gps, navigation

I am looking for an Android app that can be installed and used free of charge, that allows me to input target coordinates in the coordinate system of our planet (as numbers), and the app should guide me to that location by indicating the **direction** (and possibly the **distance**) to the coordinates from the current position of the device.

There are plenty of navigation apps available, but they

- either require an internet connection (which is not necessarily available while underway)
- or rely on map data downloaded beforehand (which means I have to know in advance where I'm going, or download a large number of maps and possibly occupy much storage space just in case)

I do not need guidance based upon a map. I want primarily the direction, and for that, I am looking for a free app as described that works **offline** and **without any map data**, just using the current position from the built-in GPS and whatever coordinates the user enters.

The only related info I could find is [this thread](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/435304-free-offline-gps-app-without-map.html), which is close in terms of the question, but only leads to the rather dissatisfying suggestion to use [GPS Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2), which did not seem to provide any such feature now that I tried it (either that, or that feature is hidden in the non-free version).

Comment: Related: [Offline map browser on Android with offline search](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82/185). Though a different focus, some of its answers might prove helpful to you. Also, from its description [Ulysse](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.binarytoys.ulysse) might be a good candidate. Some more in [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=125) :)

Comment: @Izzy: Doesn't seem so @ apps linked in other thread. As the other question explicitly adds the requirement of downloading maps (in contrast to my own requirements of not using any downloaded maps), all the suggested apps are map-based.

Comment: Yeah, sorry – notices *that part* of your question after my comment was already "fixed". // I've not used one app like that before (otherwise I'd made it an answer), but came across some. The "GPS Tools" section of my last link above should have some good candidates you might wish to take a look at – while waiting for a good answer, I mean :)

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, saw the other links only after I had responded in my comment. I'm just checking those out :-)

Comment: @Izzy: Ulysse Gizmos doesn't seem to let me add a waypoint just by typing coordinates (at least it always wants to open a map when I try adding a waypoint).

Comment: @Izzy: Unfortunately, the 35 apps linked in the list also either just show what GPS satellites my device is connected to, or somehow help GPS reception. Only very few of them provide any navigational help at all, and those few again want me to add waypoints on a map rather than accepting numerical coordinates.

Comment: Here you go: [GPS Navigation Compass](http://www.appbrain.com/app/gps-navigation-compass/com.splashpadmobile.compass) exactly fits your description. Let me know if it fits you; if it does, I'll make it an answer :)

Comment: @Izzy: That was one app I had not come across yet on my quest for anything GPS-related in the Play Store. Anyway, this looks very promising in terms of theoretical functionality, and I don't care that the UI looks a bit incomplete. I'll have to test it for a few days; will report back then.

Comment: Did you test Izzy's proposed app? Feel free to write an answer about it.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I tested it once, and it made a good first impression, however the linked website now says: "This app is unfortunately no longer available on the Android market." :(

Answer (score 3):

There is [OSMand](http://osmand.net/). It is a navigation app for which you *can* download maps, but it comes out-of-the-box with

- a (low-resolution) world map,
- a compass, showing
- the direction to target, and
- only 7 MB.

It is available on Google Play and [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.osmand.plus). So if the extra map does not bother you, go give it a try.

Comment: I use OSMAnd for this exact purpose, it is really great and you don't need to download maps if you don't want navigation assistance.