# Large Python webapp, needed to demonstrate that large Python apps start fast

Tags: web-apps, python

I want to demonstrate that even a fairly large Python webapp actually doesn't take (relatively) much time to get up and running. It currently takes at least 15 minutes to redeploy our existing application (Java on Tomcat).

What I'm looking for:

- Large (bigger is better, but at least a couple thousand lines)
- Webapp, preferably Flask, though other micro frameworks or Django or even Tornado et. al are fine.
- Database access, preferably quite a bit of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). According to cloc:

```
http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.53  T=1.0 s (388.0 files/s, 101003.0 lines/s)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python                          268          12102          18662          54967
HTML                             73            525            770           6113
CSS                              17            256            170           2940
Javascript                       23            216            314           2096
DTD                               1            200            214            564
make                              1            148             90            331
Bourne Shell                      1             12            175             45
Bourne Again Shell                2              4             16             37
YAML                              1              0              0             26
XML                               1              0              0             10
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            388          13463          20411          67129
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So that's 50,000, weighing in (according to the [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trac/1.0.1) page) at a whopping 3MB. After install, my virtualenv directory was about 20MB.

Comment: Good example. For some more details, see my answers [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185#1560), [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7492/185#7501), and [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82/185#277) to get an idea about its capabilities. It's pretty modularized, and not that difficult to enhance it with your own modules (I once contributed a Log-Viewer to it).

Answer (score 0):

[Plone](https://plone.org/) is an [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) server with [700k lines of code](https://www.openhub.net/p/plone), written in Python (on the [Zope](http://www.zope.org/) framework).
It uses a database and has a web interface.

An even bigger one was [Nuxeo](http://nuxeo.com/), but in 2005 it was [rewritten from Python to Java](http://www.theserverside.com/report/For-Nuxeo-Success-in-the-ECM-Market-Meant-Switching-from-Python-to-Java).