# Looking for on-road offline GPS/Nav software on Android

Tags: android, offline, maps, gps

I'm looking for an on-road offline GPS/navigation software for Android devices.  Offline means that it doesn't require an Internet connection to function, downloads its maps and stores them locally, and uses just the GPS of the Android device to determine the location of the user. On-road means I will primarily use the software to get driving directions.  Outdoorsey activities are a low priority bonus.

I have tried apps and software packages over Windows, Windows Mobile, Android, and online and offline and have yet to find what I am looking for.  I find that Google Maps is the most useful of the nav apps that I have used, though it's still a frustrating software for me.

I have tried:
Delorme 2009, Windows and Windows Mobile:
http://shop.delorme.com/OA_HTML/DELibeCCtpSctDspRte.jsp?section=10120&minisite=10020

MapFactor: GPS
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator

GPS Navigation (Sygic)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sygic.aura

Navmii GPS World (Free)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL

As far as always-connected GPS/Nav software, I have tried:
Google Maps
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps

Waze
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze

The features I have found that I don't like:

- Some versions of Google Maps will give directions like "use the left lanes to turn left" and I think that's ridiculous.  Just tell me to turn left.
- Google Maps can cache maps, but you can't search unless connected to The Internet
- Sometimes Google Maps will tell you far enough ahead when you are going to turn, sometimes not.
- Sometimes the software will inform you that you are about to make transition to go straight and that's a waste of informing me something and makes me distrust the software.
- Some softwares use a search methodology that makes you enter in your destination address in a specific way that is not the way you would write your destination address.  In effect it's the reverse of the address.  I have found this to be the way that stand alone GPS devices work.  I don't like this.  I prefer the flexibility that Google Maps offers, where you can enter full or partial searches and the software is smart enough to figure it out.  Modern smartphones have enough smarts to figure it out.
- The Waze UI is too busy and and is too focused on social interaction.  I am focused on getting from point A to point B.
- I forget which software it was, but there were random noises coming from it, dings, dongs, and other bell type noises.  As a new user I had no idea what was going on.  A voice enabled app should use voices to inform the user.

The features that I am looking for:

Must-have features:

- On-road GPS/Nav capabilities
- Turn by turn voice directions

Most important features:

- Offline maps for states in the USA
- Multi-state capability
- Offline search to destination
- Natural search to destination (as opposed to entering the address in reverse)
- Partial address search capability
- High accuracy results when searching (Counter example: sometimes Google will return results in the wrong state, or the wrong location of the chain restaurant)
- Voice navigation on roads
- High accuracy navigation (keeping me on the road while navigating, well thought out routes, efficient re-routes, accurate destinations; not driving off road when there is no off-road option, not turning off the interstate where there is no off-ramp, etc...)
- Android 4.x support

Important features:

- Common English voice directions: non-pedantic, non excessive, just-right directions.
- Settings and configuration options
- Maps saved to SD card

Nice-to-have features

- Import/export address book capabilities
- If connected to the Internet, traffic status/updates and redirects
- Maps/directions for the woods, trails, walking, or other non-vehicle scenarios
- Maps able to be saved to USB stick
- Cross platform support (Windows, Android, Linux)
- Android 2.x support
- Off-road, outdoorsey activities like maps for the woods, topo maps, etc.

I'm not opposed to paying for the software, but I'd prefer to try it out before buying it, read some reviews, watch some videos of it in action, or the like.

Comment: This is almost the same as [Offline map browser on Android with offline search](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82/offline-map-browser-on-android-with-offline-search), except that that question had directions as nice-to-have only and didn't care about voice quality. Still, I think most of the answers there would apply here as well.

Comment: It seems that I was in the meta forum when I searched and tagged.  I thought it was weird I found 0 results and couldn't tag "android" or "GPS".  Whoops! Thanks for fixing that!

Comment: @Gilles is definitely correct. I'd again recomment *Locus Maps* here, though it doesn't match all requirements (e.g. no cross-platform), I'm not sure about some (offline search), and I'm not sure I understand some others (partial/natural search could need a little explanation, as does "high accuracy").

Comment: I checked out Locus Maps.  I think something was lost in translation.  I'm looking primarily for on-road GPS directions, and off-road adventuring is a low priority added bonus.  Looking at the Locus Maps page and their YouTube vids, it seems that Locus Maps does all of the outdoorsey GPS stuff, and none of the on-road stuff.  I'll update the OP to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

## Here Maps

[HERE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.here.app.maps) is a surprisingly good offline navigation app made by (surprise!) Nokia.

> With HERE, you can plan your journey ahead of time and save a map of your destination right on your phone. With maps for more than a 100 countries around the world, you'll never be lost — even when offline. See exactly where you are and find the best way around with a route planner that shows you driving, public transport and walking options at a glance.
>
> When you're ready to head out, turn-by-turn, voice-guided driving and walk navigation takes you right to your destination — or use our public transport maps and schedules to get around by train or bus. With HERE, your maps are always loaded and ready to use, and you never need to rely on an internet connection.

**Screenshots**

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [Navmii](http://navmii.com/), works really good. It has all the things you ask for, the only thing I can't tell is how it acts in USA (states...), as I live in Europe.

Most fun of all: it's FREE (although it shows adds). Those adds can be removed by payment (wich I did not do, I don't mind them)